# Two polynomials which are "completely" coprime

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

I would like to ask the following question:

> Is it possible to find two non-constant polynomials $p(x), q(x)$ with integer
> coefficients, such that $\gcd(p(n), q(m))=1$ for every $(n, m)\in
>  \mathbb{N}^2$?

If such $p(x), q(x)$ exist, we will call them "completely" coprime, since all of their values will be coprime.
Obviously $p(x), q(x)$ must not have the same root, but this does not seem to help. The problem seems to be quite simple and I suspect that the answer is no, but I was unable to prove this.

Comment: How about $p=q=1$?

Comment: @ChrisBirkbeck I made an edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Noncoprime polynomial values](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239013/noncoprime-polynomial-values)

Comment: I have voted to close this question as duplicate, but it feels a little weird as it has generated interesting answers that weren't present [the previous time this question was asked](https://mathoverflow.net/q/239013/82179).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fedor Petrov has pointed out that there is a flaw in the published solution, and neither of us sees an easy way to fix the argument. Since MathOverflow will not allow me to delete the solution, I am replacing it with this text, and will change my answer to Community wiki to remove the credit.

Comment: can not we simply say that if $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ are roots of $f(x)$, then $\operatorname{Res}_x\bigl(f(x),g(x+y)\bigr)=C\prod_{i=1}^k g(y+\alpha_i)$ is a polynomial in $y$ of degree $\deg g\cdot \deg f$, thus not a constant?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sure, that's an even more efficient way to finish the proof, using the definition of the resultant instead of Bezout's identity. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, but why if $p$ divides a resultant there is a common root mod $p$? There is a common factor, not necessarily linear.

Comment: @FedorPetrov You're right, that's an error in the proof. I thought a little bit about how to fix it and haven't come up with a fix. I'll continue to think about it. Hmmm... If it's not fixable, should I delete the answer, or just edit it to point out the error?

Comment: At least it should be clarified in a disclaimer. Possibly somebody may see how to fix it. But I am sceptical on this:(

Answer (score 38):

Let me rename to $f$ and $g$ the two polynomials (which you called $p$ and $q$ in the question) as this will make notations less confusing.

Clearly we can assume that $f$ and $g$ are irreducible and distinct.  Let $K$ be the decomposition field of $fg$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Possibly excluding finitely many primes that divide the leading coefficient of $f$ or $g$ or at which $f$ or $g$ ramifies, to say that a prime $p$ splits completely in $K$ means that $fg$ has $\deg f + \deg g$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and certainly implies that $f$ and $g$ have roots there.  Now by Čebotarëv's density theorem (or something weaker), there is a positive density of such primes, so we can find $p$ such that both $f$ and $g$ have roots, say $\bar m,\bar n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  Lifting them arbitrarily to integers, we see that $p$ divides both $f(m)$ and $g(n)$, which are therefore not relatively prime.

Comment: Regarding "something weaker", I asked this very question a while ago and got some excellent answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15220/is-there-an-elementary-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-completely-split-primes

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais When you say that you asked "this very question", I assumed you meant you'd asked the OP's question, and then wondered why the OP's question wasn't then flagged as a duplicate. So you might want to clarify that what you asked was for a more elementary proof that infinitely many primes split completely, which is also a great question, of course.

Comment: Also "a while ago" is a nice understatement for a question from the first half year of this site's existence!